# Update record in a table where the condition depends on other table

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 table in MySQL

- Project:

  ```
  ProjectID         ProjectStatus
      1                    0
      2                    0
      3                    0
      4                    0
      5                    0
  ```
- Quotation:

  ```
  QuotationID         ProjectID            QuotationNumber
      1                    1                     X001
      2                    2                     X002
      3                    3                     X003
      4                    1                     X004
      5                    2                     X005
  ```

I need a SQL Syntax which can update or edit ProjectStatus in table Project

if the project is in the quotation table then change ProjectStatus to 1
if the project is NOT in the quotation table then change ProjectStatus to 2

So after i runt that SQL syntax, the Project table will become like this:

- Project(After Query Run):

  ```
  ProjectID         ProjectStatus
      1                    1
      2                    1
      3                    1
      4                    2
      5                    2
  ```

I tried many queries, but i cant figure it out.

Anyone  can help please.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could also do this as two updates (perhaps inside a transaction) - and use an inner join instead of an outer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Project
LEFT OUTER JOIN Quotation
ON Project.ProjectID = Quotation.ProjectID
SET Project.ProjectStatus = IF(Quotation.ProjectID IS NULL, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Project p
LEFT JOIN Quotation q
ON p.ProjectID = q.ProjectID
SET ProjectStatus = IF(q.ProjectID IS NULL, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Lol, virtually exactly the same answer as mine

Comment: @Kickstart Yeah, I was a few seconds behind you. I had a feeling if I refreshed I would have seen that mine was redundant, but what the heck...

Comment: It happens. But the responses are SO similar even with the formatting. Just you aliased the tables, which I almost did (and if I did I would probably have used the same alias names)

Comment: @Kickstart The strange thing is that it's been 15 minutes and no one has posted a version using `EXISTS` yet. :)

Comment: Lol. Or even IN and a subselect. Or even a co related subselect as part of the assignment.